# Careers "add an answer" link doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Careers seems to think I have no answers on Stack Overflow, and when I try to paste in an answer URL, such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325085/when-to-prefer-json-over-xml/329683#329683`, there's a little "I'm talking to the server" animation that displays next to the input box; other than that, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your account didn't associate correctly.  You should be good to go now.